# javascript in animated button

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I incorporate javascript to animate this button? I got the CSS (color changing) part to work but not the animated bubble part.
https://codepen.io/Grsmto/pen/RPQPPB

The style.css and script.js are in the same folder as the index.html

Here's what my index.html looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

</head>
<body>                              

<div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" class="goo">
  <defs>
    <filter id="goo">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur" />
      <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9" result="goo" />
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>

<span class="button--bubble__container">
  <a href="#" target="_blank" class="button button--bubble">
    Click this button
  </a>
  <span class="button--bubble__effect-container">
    <span class="circle top-left"></span>
    <span class="circle top-left"></span>
    <span class="circle top-left"></span>

    <span class="button effect-button"></span>

    <span class="circle bottom-right"></span>
    <span class="circle bottom-right"></span>
    <span class="circle bottom-right"></span>
  </span>
</span>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for answer this basic question!

Comment: Did you try adding a `<script>` tag within the `<head>` tag at the top, which links to your `script.js` file?  It could go right below the CSS `<link>` tag.

Comment: Bubble seems to work here-- Chrome/Mac

Comment: bubble works for me as well - awesome button; chrome \ win 10

Comment: update -- added <script src="script.js"></script> to the <head> tag at the top and the bubble still doesn't appear to work?